# Raise/lower brightness is extremely slow

Tags: mac, display, macos

Whenever I try to raise/lower my screen brightness with the <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> buttons, it takes a couple of seconds before the brightness changes, and I can't stop it from raising/lowering the brightness

Raising/lowering the brightness is also a very slow process

Is there any way to bring this back to normal function/speed?

I have a mid 2012 13" MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra.

Comment: Sorry, editing to make clearer

Comment: @Allan mid-2012 13' macbook pro macOS Sierra

Comment: Have you tried booting into Safe Mode (hold `Shift` while booting)  and seeing if the problem persists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you reset your SMC (System Management Controller).

The process can be tricky, but you will know if you succeeded if the MagSafe Plug light changes color momentarily as you do the reset.

The reset of SMC depends on your Mac model, so follow the [instructions here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

Comment: Added model in comment

Comment: Two things: what happens if I don't succeed, and the light always flickers :/

Comment: The light will briefly change color (not flicker)

Comment: Hey, it worked for about a day, and now it's back to how it was. Is there a more permanent fix?

Comment: so something is corrupting your SMC, try resetting it again to confirm.

Comment: Ok, I've reset it, do I just wait for it to stop working like it should again?

Comment: That might take some more investigation. I would suggest to close this question, since it works after reset, and open new question, about why or what changes the SMC settings. To analyze, we will  need console report, terminal report, running processes report ect...

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341014/something-is-corrupting-my-smc-why-or-what-changes-the-smc-settings

Comment: Can you please help me with the smc question?