# Something is corrupting my SMC, why or what changes the SMC settings?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, power-management

I asked a question that led up to this: [Raise/lower brightness is extremely slow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340748/raise-lower-brightness-is-extremely-slow/340755?noredirect=1#comment442969_340755)

It works just fine after SMC Reset. But the next day same problem.

It appears that the problem is that something is corrupting my SMC

> so something is corrupting your SMC, try resetting it again to confirm. – Buscar웃 12 hours ago

I reset my SMC yesterday, and it's already messed up today

I have a mid 2012 MacBook Pro

So, basically, what/how is something changing/corrupting my SMC, and how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: can anyone please help me with this?