# My SMC keeps corrupting, even after I reset it

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, power-management

The SMC on my 2012-MPB keeps corrupting, causing the computer to not wake up or restart. I've tried resetting it multiple times, but the issue still occurs.

The only solution I've found is disconnecting and then reconnecting the internal battery, which is quite problematic. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?

Comment: This is becoming a big problem, and I'm having to reset it constantly. Is there a permanent fix for this?

Comment: How did you determine that your SMC is corrupted?

Comment: From here @Allan https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/340748/305111

Comment: That's not a diagnostic for a corrupt SMC.  Are you saying you're having brightness issues?

Comment: No, I also am having waking up from sleep issues, and a couple of other issues that Apple mentions. Also, resetting my SMC fixes the problem, at least temporarily

Comment: It could be anything from a faulty SMC chip to faulty components (resistors, capacitors, even circuit traces) that are feeding faulty signaling to the SMC.  In other words, this could be a logic board issue.  If the battery drops to point where the SMC no longer receives power, it will automatically reset itself.  See:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/304679/119271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMC problems could be related to the battery itself.  That age of laptop doesn't have a separate battery - as in the average non-Apple motherboard which has a CMOS battery on the motherboard, so SMC would be using battery power to store settings.

If the battery's shot, SMC loses it's settings at whatever point the battery drains itself.

See if you can borrow another of the same model with a healthy-ish battery to test with for a bit...

Comment: I have two identical computers, this is happening to both. Unfortunately (which kinda makes sense why this is happening now) neither have batteries :/ one of them died yesterday. Would it make sense then that when they are plugged in, after restarting with no battery, that there are SMC problems?

Comment: if the SMC settings are getting dropped every time the battery drains itself, then yeah, it would try to rebuild them on the next restart(which probably looks like it restarting a bunch of times on its own, then finally figuring it out and starting up). plugged in would only hold the settings as long as it's powered on, since there's no backup battery for those settings.